# Log out when sending a form

Tags: django

I've created an app where you can make comment (which sends a form to a database and saves it) if you're login on only, but when I press the button "Create" instead of redirecting me to the page where it show all the comments, it logs me out and bring me back to the "log out" view (which is  / )

the create Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="create_comment">
        <h2>Write a comment</h2>
        <form class="site-form" action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The Views of Create:

```
@login_required(login_url='/userprofile/login/')
def comments_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = forms.CreateComment(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/usercomments')
    else:
        form = forms.CreateComment()
    return render(request,'usercomments/comments_create.html', {'form':form})
```

Log out view:

```
def logout_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        pass
```

usercomments Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.comments_list, name="list"),
    url(r'^create/$', views.comments_create, name="create"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',views.comments_detail, name="detail"),
    ]
```

userprofile urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'userprofile'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_view, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_view, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.logout_view, name="logout"),
]
```

Comment: can you upload you url file as well.

Comment: well it looks like when you hit the submit button the view redirects to "redirect('/usercomments')" but the action is "{% url 'create' %}" am I right?

Comment: yes, it should be like that but instead i got redirect to my log out view and i can see it in my terminal.